# Alterar valores do eixo Y no chart js

Tags: jquery, chartjs

Como alterar esses valores do eixo Y no chart js, esses valores de 5 a 50 foram colocados automaticamente pelo plugin, queria modifica-los.

[image: chart js]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Chart.js o eixo Y é determinado pela propriedade [datasets vê a documentação](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) o qual pode vim do banco ou inserido em hard code como é feito no exemplo abaixo.

```js
var barData = {
  labels: ["Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho"],
  datasets: [{
    fillColor: "#48A497",
    strokeColor: "#48A4D1",
    data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 80]
  }]
}
var income = document.getElementById("graficoBar").getContext("2d");

new Chart(income).Bar(barData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="graficoBar" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```